# EOFError: marshal data too short

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Why do I get the following error when I run the django server and how do I fix it ? :

```
EOFError: marshal data too short
```

## details

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f6e5dbacea0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/aphya1/work/1-erp-project/ERP/mis/mis/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
    url(r'^hr/', include('hr.urls', namespace='hr')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/aphya1/work/1-erp-project/ERP/mis/hr/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from hr import views
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 765, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 476, in _compile_bytecode
EOFError: marshal data too short
```

Comment: Because Python can not handle the marshal data, it is too short. Provide more marshal data :).

Comment: But now siriously: you need to provide more context. What part of the code is doing this?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/easB1mE3rJY

Comment: Seems to have to do with corrupted `.pyc` files

Comment: I had the same error. In my case, thanks to @sshashank124's comment, I can fix this problem by deleting not only `__pychache__` of the main program directory but also ones of imported packages. You may find the `__pycache__` by `find` command like this: `$ find /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ -name __pycache__ | grep django/utils` or so.

Comment: In my case it has just corrupted py files sent over with scp and re-doing it fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

I also encountered the error:

> EOFError: marshal data too short.

Even though no changes were made to any of the existing files, this error was thrown.

Some *.pyc files get created automatically which are compiled byte code of a script, which gets dynamically created when a Python script runs to speed up future launches.

I am using an Oracle VM VirtualBox manager, working on `Python`.

I was trying to install `pyspark`. 
The spark folder structure was something like this

```
spark****/python/pyspark
```

Under this folder contained a folder by name '__pycache__'
I went to the pyspark folder and deleted the '__pycache__' folder using the command:

```
rm -r __pycache__/
```

This eliminated the error for me and I am now able to import pyspark.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: It happened to me when I did a search and replace in a file tree without filtering out .pyc files. But any other scenario that modifies/corrupts .pyc files could cause it.

Answer (score 10):

I delete all `.pyc` files using terminal and it worked for me

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

Comment: Cool!!!, You're a saviour.

Comment: spot on :), cheers